# Angular ng-container not showing the values

Tags: css, angular, typescript2.0

I am using ng-container  to display the ng content value which I have written in parent component

some-test-comp.ts

```
<div class="some-test-com" >
 
  <div class="some">
    
      <ng-content select="[value]"></ng-content>
   
  </div>
  
</div>
```

some.test-com.css

```
  .some {
position: relative;
  }
```

home-comp.ts
It routes me to another component ts. Routing is working in a proper manner.

```
 <router-outlet> <router-outlet>
```

another-component.ts

```
 <some-test-com>


<ng-container value>
<div>Hello<div>

<ng-container>

</some-test-com>

<h3>hai<h3>  //I can see this line but not the above  Hello.The dive for Hello is present but the content is blank
```

I can see this line but not the above  Hello.The dive for Hello is present but the content is blank

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you getting any console errors, or is there CSS that might be hiding your `some` content?

Comment: Okay.How do i overide css of some-test-com

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code, but in general, you have to provide a rule more specific than the one currently applied.

Comment: updated the css file.  Could you please help me how to override?

Comment: Your problem seems to be a simple typo: <div>Hello<div> those are 2 opening divs.. Also the same issue with your ng-container.

Comment: I have no idea what CSS actually needs to be written, but to make a rule more specific, it would have to be: .some.something-else { ... }